# CakePhp2.x use CronJobs in windows

Tags: cakephp, cron

I have my Shell Class in the directory app/Shell
And cakeShell in the directory app/Console/
So When I execute the command 
fullPath/app/ cake order
I get the error **Shell Class orderShell could not be found**

That's my Shell Class Code :

```
<?php
namespace app\Shell;
use Cake\Console\Shell;

class OrderShell extends Shell {

        function main() // main needs to define
        {
                App::import(‘Component’, ‘BusinessLogic’);
                $this->BusinessLogic = &new BusinessLogic();

                $option = !empty($this->args[0]) ? $this->args[0] : ”;
                echo ‘Cron started without any issue.’;

                switch ($option)
                {
                        case ‘first’:
                        $result= $this->BusinessLogic->first_method();
                        break;
                        case ‘second’:
                        $result= $this->BusinessLogic->deleteauto();
                        break;
                        default:
                        echo ‘No Parameters passed .’;
                }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP 2.x doesn't use namespaces so the `namespace` statement at top of your file is most likely the cause of your problem.

Also you shouldn't be importing components in your shell. If you find yourself needing that it means that functionality belongs inside the model class instead.